# Building Qt 5.5 from sources fails with strange error message

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5, qt5.5

I try to build Qt5.5 from sources using windows and the VS2013 compiler according to the description on Qt webpage. Everything seems to build fine, except QWebEngine, there compilation fails with

```
( if not exist Makefile.core_gyp_generator D:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\qtbase\bin\qmakeD:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\qtwebengine\src\core\core_gyp_generator.pro -o Makefile.core_gyp_generator ) && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.core_gyp_generator
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '(' : return code '0x3'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Why does QWebEngine try to access git? All sources are held locally, no GIT repository is involved. So any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to install `git`, as the installer is telling you to :) "All sources are held locally" Obviously, they are not.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: sorry but this is nonsense

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found it: the install-directory (specified with configure option -prefix) was missing. Why this ends up in this wrong and irritating error message ... only the guys from Qt may know...